# Misplaced footer when viewed on iPad's Safari

Tags: css, ipad, footer

A website that I'm currently working on works completely fine in regards to the footer, however when viewing the website on the iPad's Safari, the footer is misplaced quite a bit above the bottom of the page and after an hour of trial and error I'm not getting anywhere fast. I was hoping someone had this very issue and can perhaps aid me by explain what you did to resolve the issue.

This is the basic markup of my HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <iframe></iframe> <!-- This is where the different pages are set -->
    </form>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}

.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6d8085;
}
```

Chrome

[image]

iPad

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *position:fixed;*

or changing *height* to *min-height* on your css declaration

Basically your content is peeking out of your page. To see this add *body{background-color:red;}*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After careful consideration, my boss and I decided that having the footer fixed rather than absolute would be alright with the design of our website.

Comment: It's worth noting that Mobile Safari on iPads has been the bain of my developing life recently. There are a few very peculiar rendering issues esp on older versions. Glad you were able to move on ;)